# Baldurs Gate GOG version not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine

I upgraded my Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 and Baldurs Gate 1 will not work anymore in wine. Here is the error message:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000004 in 32-bit
code (0x7c851b20). Register dump:  CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b
FS:0063 GS:006b  EIP:7c851b20 ESP:0033ada4 EBP:0033ae6c
EFLAGS:00010216(  R- --  I   -A-P- )  EAX:00000000 EBX:7cbd3000
ECX:7bfd1740 EDX:7c0d0b70  ESI:7c09e1bc EDI:7cbdb060 Stack dump:
0x0033ada4:  000080e1 00008367 00000000 00000000 0x0033adb4:  7c09e1bc
7c614849 7cbd3000 004f1a04 0x0033adc4:  00000000 7bfd1740 7c0d0b70
00000002 0x0033add4:  7c0b5fa8 00000280 000001e0 00000000 0x0033ade4: 
00000000 00000280 000001e0 00000280 0x0033adf4:  000005a0 7c09e1bc
db5a8d00 7c283898 Backtrace:
=>0 0x7c851b20 in i915_dri.so (+0x32db20) (0x0033ae6c) 0x7c851b20: pushl    0x4(%eax) Modules: Module   Address         Debug info  Name (146
modules) PE   400000-  8bb000   Deferred        bgmain2
ELF 7b800000-7ba54000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>  
\-PE    7b810000-7ba54000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bacf000-7bafb000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7bafb000-7bb87000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7bb87000-7bc00000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7bc00000-7bcda000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>  
\-PE    7bc10000-7bcda000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bceb000-7bd4b000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7bd4b000-7bdd3000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-8.0.so
ELF 7bdd3000-7bf00000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>  
\-PE    7bdf0000-7bf00000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7bf26000-7bf2f000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7bf2f000-7bf89000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7c407000-7c40e000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7c40e000-7c418000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7c418000-7c424000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF 7c445000-7c46d000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>  
\-PE    7c450000-7c46d000   \               winepulse
ELF 7c46d000-7c48f000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>  
\-PE    7c470000-7c48f000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7c4a4000-7c4db000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7c4db000-7c4e7000   Deferred        libpciaccess.so.0
ELF 7c4e7000-7c4f5000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7c4f5000-7c4ff000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7c4ff000-7c524000   Deferred        libdrm_intel.so.1
ELF 7c524000-7cbde000   Dwarf           i915_dri.so
ELF 7cbde000-7cbff000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7cbff000-7cc11000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7cc11000-7cc17000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7cc17000-7cc32000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7cc32000-7cc35000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7cc35000-7cc39000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7cc39000-7cc55000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7cc55000-7cc5d000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7cc5d000-7cccc000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d074000-7d098000   Deferred        imm32<elf>  
\-PE    7d080000-7d098000   \               imm32
ELF 7d1de000-7d1f4000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7d1f4000-7d269000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF 7d269000-7d286000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7d286000-7d335000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7d335000-7d35b000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7d35b000-7d381000   Deferred        libselinux.so.1
ELF 7d381000-7d40f000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7d40f000-7d428000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7d428000-7d482000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d482000-7d50e000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7d50e000-7d543000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7d543000-7d57f000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7d5e4000-7d5e8000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7d5e8000-7d5f1000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d5f1000-7d5fa000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d5fa000-7d60f000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7d60f000-7d643000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7d643000-7d6a4000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d6a4000-7d6b1000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7d6b1000-7d6e2000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d6e2000-7d7b9000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d7b9000-7d7cd000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7d7cd000-7d925000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7d925000-7d977000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d977000-7d9fe000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7da1f000-7da54000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>  
\-PE    7da30000-7da54000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7da54000-7da5b000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7da5b000-7da66000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7da66000-7da79000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7da79000-7da7d000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7da7d000-7da8a000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7da8a000-7da96000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7da96000-7da9d000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7da9d000-7daa1000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7daa1000-7daa8000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7daa8000-7daac000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7daac000-7dad2000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7dad2000-7dc1d000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dc1d000-7dc32000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7dc32000-7dc35000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7dc35000-7dc39000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7dc39000-7dc3e000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7dc3e000-7dc43000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7dc43000-7dc51000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7dc53000-7dce0000   Deferred        winex11<elf>  
\-PE    7dc60000-7dce0000   \               winex11
ELF 7dd62000-7dd8c000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd8c000-7ddd5000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7ddd5000-7de00000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7de00000-7de1b000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7de1b000-7decb000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7deec000-7df01000   Deferred        comm.drv16.so
PE  7def0000-7df01000   Deferred        comm.drv16
ELF 7df01000-7df16000   Deferred        system.drv16.so
PE  7df10000-7df16000   Deferred        system.drv16
ELF 7df16000-7dfbe000   Deferred        krnl386.exe16.so
PE  7df20000-7dfbe000   Deferred        krnl386.exe16
 ELF    7dfbe000-7e0dc000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>  
 \-PE   7dfe0000-7e0dc000   \               opengl32
 ELF    7e0dc000-7e20e000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>  
 \-PE   7e0f0000-7e20e000   \               wined3d
 ELF    7e20e000-7e281000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>  
 \-PE   7e220000-7e281000   \               ddraw
 ELF    7e281000-7e2c8000   Deferred        dsound<elf>  
 \-PE   7e290000-7e2c8000   \               dsound
ELF 7e2c8000-7e2f2000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>  
\-PE    7e2d0000-7e2f2000   \               msacm32
ELF 7e2f2000-7e36e000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>  
\-PE    7e300000-7e36e000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e36e000-7e49d000   Deferred        ole32<elf>  
\-PE    7e380000-7e49d000   \               ole32
ELF 7e49d000-7e555000   Deferred        winmm<elf>  
\-PE    7e4a0000-7e555000   \               winmm
ELF 7e555000-7e595000   Deferred        dplayx<elf>  
\-PE    7e560000-7e595000   \               dplayx
ELF 7e595000-7e5d1000   Deferred        winspool<elf>  
\-PE    7e5a0000-7e5d1000   \               winspool
ELF 7e5d1000-7e6c6000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>  
\-PE    7e5e0000-7e6c6000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e6c6000-7e73c000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>  
\-PE    7e6d0000-7e73c000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e73c000-7e965000   Deferred        shell32<elf>  
\-PE    7e750000-7e965000   \               shell32
ELF 7e965000-7ea4a000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>  
\-PE    7e970000-7ea4a000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7ea4a000-7eab6000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>  
\-PE    7ea60000-7eab6000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eab6000-7ebcd000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>  
\-PE    7eac0000-7ebcd000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ebcd000-7ed1b000   Deferred        user32<elf>  
\-PE    7ebe0000-7ed1b000   \               user32
ELF 7ed1b000-7ed4f000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>  
\-PE    7ed20000-7ed4f000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7ed4f000-7ed62000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed62000-7ed6f000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed6f000-7ed8a000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef8a000-7efdf000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe7000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>  
\-PE    7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f7411000-f7416000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7416000-f75cc000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f75cd000-f75ea000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7600000-f760a000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f760b000-f77c0000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f77c2000-f77e7000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77e9000-f77ea000   Deferred        [vdso].so Threads: process  tid 
prio (all id:s are in hex) 0000000e services.exe    0000001f    0
0000001e    0   00000019    0   00000018    0   00000016    0   00000014 
0   00000010    0   0000000f    0 00000012 winedevice.exe   0000001d    0
0000001a    0   00000017    0   00000013    0 0000001b plugplay.exe
00000021    0   00000020    0   0000001c    0 00000022 explorer.exe
00000024    0   00000023    0 00000030 (D) C:\Program Files
(x86)\GOG.com\Baldurs Gate\BGMain2.exe  0000003a   15   00000039   15
00000038    0   00000037    0   00000036   15   00000035    0   00000034 
0   00000033   15   00000032    0   00000031    0 <== System information:
Wine build: wine-1.6.2
Platform: i386 (WOW64)
Host system: Linux
Host version: 4.4.0-51-generic
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Baldur's Gate has a Linux port, so you don't need Wine in the first place.

Comment: I'll try reinstalling it and if that does not work i'll try gemrb

Comment: Wine 1.7 might also give you better results. But the native port (of the enhanced edition) is pretty decent.

Comment: The install worked. I loaded my old saved game. When I pressed "Alt+Enter" assumed to go out of full-screen mode , it crashed? The wine version is 1.6.2. I can't upgrade to wine 1.7?